# Fields in the conditionalpanel need to be placed next to sidepanel

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I'm developing an application in Shiny. I need to place the fields in the conditionalPanel next to the sidePanel but with my existing code it comes below the Go button. The conditionalpanel should be displayed only when Go is clicked and selectInput is chosen. Could someone help with this please?

I tried using column(3,*), wellpanel nothing worked.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("Nomenclature Calculator"),
    fluidRow(
        column(3, wellPanel(
            textInput("account","Enter the Account Name",""),
            tags$hr(),
            textInput("advertiser","Enter the Advertiser Name",""),
            tags$hr(),
            textInput("insertionorderid","Enter the Insertion Order ID",""),
            tags$hr(),
            textInput("campaignname","Enter the Campaign Name",""),
            tags$hr(),
            selectInput("dropdown", "Choose from the drop down",
                        list("flight","tactic","AD-Video","AD-NonVideo","Pixel"),selected = FALSE ,multiple = FALSE,selectize = FALSE, size=4),
            tags$hr(),
            actionButton("goButton", "Go")
        )),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.dropdown == 'flight'",
            textInput("flightname","Enter the flight Name",""),
            selectInput("addedvalue", "Added Value:",
                        c("No","Yes")),
            tags$hr(),
            actionButton("go", "Go")
            #textInput("Tactic Name",paste0("Enter the",input$dropdown, "Name"))
        ),
))
```

The conditionalpanel should be displayed only when Go is clicked and selectInput is chosen. And next to the sidepanel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Nomenclature Calculator"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      textInput("account","Enter the Account Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("advertiser","Enter the Advertiser Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("insertionorderid","Enter the Insertion Order ID",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("campaignname","Enter the Campaign Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      selectInput("dropdown", "Choose from the drop down",
                  list("flight","tactic","AD-Video","AD-NonVideo","Pixel"),
                  selected = FALSE ,
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selectize = FALSE, 
                  size=4),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    )),
    column(3, conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.dropdown == 'flight'",
      textInput("flightname","Enter the flight Name",""),
      selectInput("addedvalue", "Added Value:",
                  c("No","Yes")),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("go", "Go")
      #textInput("Tactic Name",paste0("Enter the",input$dropdown, "Name")),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.dropdown == 'tactic'",
        textInput("tacticname","Enter the tactic Name",""),
        tags$hr(),
        actionButton("go1", "Go")
        #textInput("Tactic Name",paste0("Enter the",input$dropdown, "Name"))
    )),
    column(3,conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.dropdown == 'AD-NonVideo'",
        textInput("channelname","Enter the Channel Name",""),
        tags$hr(),
        textInput("adname","Enter the AD Name",""),
        tags$hr(),
        numericInput("width","Enter the AD Width",""),
        tags$hr(),
        numericInput("height","Enter the AD Height",""),
        tags$hr(),
        actionButton("go2", "Go")
    ))
           )

    )
  )
)
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for your reply. But when I select "tactic" from selectInput, the conditionalPanel for "Tactic" should appear. It does work but there is one panel space between the sidepanel and the tactic one. I have edited your code to include the other 2 options.

Comment: You are welcome. If you haven't already, I would suggest watching this [video](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) on Shiny. It has been very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your conditional panels are mutually exclusive, you can put them into a single `column`. In this way you won't have undesired white space.

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Nomenclature Calculator"),
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
      textInput("account","Enter the Account Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("advertiser","Enter the Advertiser Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("insertionorderid","Enter the Insertion Order ID",""),
      tags$hr(),
      textInput("campaignname","Enter the Campaign Name",""),
      tags$hr(),
      selectInput("dropdown", "Choose from the drop down",
                  list("flight","tactic","AD-Video","AD-NonVideo","Pixel"),
                  selected = FALSE ,
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  selectize = FALSE, 
                  size=4),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    )),
    column(9, 
           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.dropdown == 'flight'",
             textInput("flightname","Enter the flight Name",""),
             selectInput("addedvalue", "Added Value:",
                         c("No","Yes")),
             tags$hr(),
             actionButton("go", "Go")
           ),
           #textInput("Tactic Name",paste0("Enter the",input$dropdown, "Name")),
           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.dropdown == 'tactic'",
             textInput("tacticname","Enter the tactic Name",""),
             tags$hr(),
             actionButton("go1", "Go")
             #textInput("Tactic Name",paste0("Enter the",input$dropdown, "Name"))
           ),
           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.dropdown == 'AD-NonVideo'",
             textInput("channelname","Enter the Channel Name",""),
             tags$hr(),
             textInput("adname","Enter the AD Name",""),
             tags$hr(),
             numericInput("width","Enter the AD Width",""),
             tags$hr(),
             numericInput("height","Enter the AD Height",""),
             tags$hr(),
             actionButton("go2", "Go")
           ))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input,output){})
```